# Having trouble with mysql query using date functions

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to write a mysql query that retrieves the count of a lot of things. One of the things I need to know is how many entries have a date that is less than 1 month old compared to the current date at the time of the query. I have searched on stack overflow a lot and consulted the mysql documentation, but nothing I am trying seems to work. It keeps telling me I have the wrong syntax. I am at a loss.

I have a lot going on this query, and everything else seems to be working fine.

I am using mysql and phpmyadmin to manage my data base, and I am programming in a C#/visual studio environment. I don't know exactly which version of mysql I am using, but according to the documentation of phpmyadmin I am using at least version 5.0. I looked up the documentation for mysql v5.0 and I looked at the more recent versions, and the sql functions I am trying to use have not changed. So there shouldn't be a reason this query doesn't work, but never the less it doesn't work.

```
SELECT count(*) total, ... sum(case where Date <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) then 1 else 0 end) lastmonth from table;
```

If I remove the sum statement above the rest of the query does work. The sum statement before it is deliminated by a comma, and I can't see anything in the syntax that is wrong, so it must have something to do with the sql functions in the where statement. I copied that statement verbatim from the mysql documentation page, only changing the name of the variable it is compared to and the interval to 1 month.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

So I am completely stuck. Could use some help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a solution working using different functions. I think the problem was that CURDATE() is not a function that mysql server recognizes, but the CURRENT_DATE() is. Strange, the mysql documentation says they are the same. For reference, here is the query I ended up settling on:

```
sum(case when MONTH(Date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) then 1 else 0 end) lastmonth
```

After reviewing my requirements as it turned out I need a query that retrieved the count for the number of 'Date' within the last month, ie starting from the first of the current month and going to the last day of the current month.